# Batch - execute command line to variable

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I'm trying to get identity type from application pools in IIS in .bat file.
This give me a list of pool names:

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd list apppool /text:name
```

For example, I have pool named "DefaultAppPool" and I get it identity type with command line

```
appcmd.exe list apppool "DefaultAppPool" /text:processModel.identityType
```

Now, i want to do that automaticlly and the problem is I don't now how to set command line to some variable. I tried this:

```
SET appPoolList = appcmd list apppool /text:name
```

but it does't work. This is all my example below:

```
cd %windir%\system32\inetsrv
appcmd list apppool /text:name
@echo off
SET appPoolList = appcmd list apppool /text:name

for %%x in (      
      %appPoolList%
       ) do (
        appcmd.exe list apppool "x" /text:processModel.identityType
       )
pause
```